# Atom-Editor window pane resizeing

Tags: atom-editor

I'm having an issue where the focused window pane is very small.
I tried rm ~/.atom, but it did not change anything.
I've also tried to delete and reinstall atom.
Does anyone know how to reset the view? Or increase the window pane size?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reset the window pane size via command `atom --clear-window-state`